# Suggestion for C IDE?

Tags: c++, c, windows, ide

I used  to use gcc compiler on my unix machine. I am now forced to work on a windows machine. Is there any cool IDE or a simple editor for C with a unix terminal like feel (`Black Screen and colored syntax` on it :))

What other editors/IDE are as robust as gcc for windows? Also what is your personal favorite. I would like a try a few of the those before I stick with one.

Thanks.

Comment: I think you're talking about an IDE, not a compiler.  A compiler won't have "black screen and colored syntax".

Comment: You're looking for a C compiler with a black screen terminal feel? I'm sure you'd be happy with Cygwin/Mingw, although they don't force any IDE on you any more than gcc does on Unix. You are aware that it was not gcc that had black screen and colored syntax when you were using it on Unix, right?

Comment: haha...I am aware of that...I guess I am just used to calling it that way

Comment: Your question is still a bit confused - the title says "C compiler", it's tagged as both C and C++, and I'm not sure what you're going for with an "editor...as robust as gcc".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are used to a Unix-y feel and are looking for a text editor, I'd honestly avoid installing Visual Studio. It's a nice IDE, but it is very heavyweight and perhaps much more than you are asking for. That said, you might of course find that you like it, but be aware that you are potentially looking at a several-hundred-megabytes download, 2 gigs for the full package IIRC.

Netbeans is good too, but fairly heavy, and a little difficult to get set up correctly with C and C++, at least last time I tried. It's a good alternative to VS, though.

I'd go for a more lightweight solution, like Notepad++, vim for Windows, or my personal favourite, Geany - http://www.geany.org/

Getting the black background & colored syntax is possible on basically any advanced text editor/IDE nowadays.

As for the compiler, MinGW is probably your best bet. Or you could nick the compiler & toolset that comes with Visual Studio Express :)

Answer (score 13):

Visual Studio.  You can change the fonts & colors however you want.  I have been using the same coloring scheme since Borland Turbo C++ back in the 80's -- yellow text on a dark blue background.

Comment: And of course you can invoke the compiler from the command line, if you really want that oldschool terminal feel. :)

Comment: Let's not forget to mention that the VS Express edition is available completely free, and it's quite featureful despite not being the full-featured professional edition.

Answer (score 12):

VIM or Emacs. Though I personally will never use anything other than VS :)

Comment: VIM emulation layer for VS at http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/59ca71b3-a4a3-46ca-8fe1-0e90e3f79329

Answer (score 6):

Cygwin is your friend. It gives you all the nice unixy stuff that you miss! :)

In terms of cool IDEs that will integrate nicely with gcc on Cygwin, you should try Netbeans, Eclipse (with CDT) - both require a decent JVM. If you do get Cygwin installed, there's xemacs and gvim I believe that you can get for it...

IMHO stick with Netbeans...

Comment: You can install native [Windows Emacs](http://ourcomments.org/Emacs/EmacsW32.html#form3) too.

Comment: I've had good results with Netbeans as well. Works well and doesn't try to do be everything to everyone

Answer (score 4):

[Zeus](http://www.zeusedit.com) is a very nice programmer's editor. I just love it's *Brief keyboard* emulation.

Answer (score 3):

IIRC  DOS command prompt can change its color. Have you tried [Cygwin](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cygwin) and [MinGW](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MinGW)?

Answer (score 3):

mingw is Minimum Gnu for Windows.  There are several add on packages to it, but it has `gcc` and `g++`.  Occasionally there is an issue with some tool not acting exactly right with executables having `.exe` on their end or `/` and `\\` in output statements, but it's pretty decent.  I can't remember, but I think that there may be some reason that you can't run gdb in Windows, but I could be wrong.

You can also get versions of most of the *nix text editors for Windows.  gVim is available if you like vi or vim.  Versions of vi and vim for the command line are also available, but don't always act right with resized windows.  gVim and vim can do syntax highlighting if you tell them to in the configuration file.

The last couple of versions of Windows have had (or been able to freely download and install) PowerShell, which I suggest you get.  It is different from a *nix shell in many many ways, but often (not always) you can get away with using it just like a *nix shell.  If you use pipes in it you should know that it likes to turn everything into utf-16, though.  The main good thing I've found when using it as a better DOS window is that you can resize the window more freely.  You can still use old DOS windows, though.

Another alternative is cygwin, which besides just the command line tools, presents more of a *nix environment for your programs.  It includes libraries that make things look more like you are running on Linux from your programs' point of view (simulating many Linux system calls, for instance).  I used this a long time ago, but it had some pretty severe problems back then.  I have heard great things about it since then, but I have not had enough of a reason to try it out again.

Comment: gdb is available for Windows.  See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/170097/adding-gdb-to-mingw).

Answer (score 2):

Visual Studio will be your best bet. Others have mentioned the free Express version which will probably be sufficient for your needs. Visual Studio is not only an IDE, it has Microsoft's compiler bundled with it. Since the choice of IDEs is vast, I'll leave it to you to choose the one you'll be comfortable with.

The venerable GNU gcc compiler is also available on Windows using Cygwin or MinGW.

If you want something pretty cutting edge, compiler wise, you should check out [clang](http://clang.llvm.org/). For various reasons, this is the C compiler to keep your eyes on. It's relatively new and was built with IDE support in mind.

Answer (score 1):

When visual studio already being mentioned, I have to mention Slickedit, not a IDE but a fantastic editor.

http://www.slickedit.com

Answer (score 1):

I recommend [codelite](http://codelite.org) - cross platform, free IDE designed for GNU toolchain.

Answer (score 0):

Visual Studio 2010 has an express edition that's doanloadable for free. 
[link text](http://www.microsoft.com/express/Downloads/)

gcc via Cygwin is another awesome choice esp. if you want to use Emacs as your IDE[link text](http://www.cygwin.com/).

Personally, I tend to use both. I heavily lean towards Visual Studio 2010, but occasionally compile using gcc to make sure that both compilers are working the same way. This used to be beneficial in the past (pre VS2010), but I haven't had much success in catching VS2010 make mistakes - yet.

In terms of the overall experience of integrated development, debugging etc., it's hard to beat VS2010.

Answer (score 0):

Net beans
Code block
Dev c++
code lite are good IDE