# Connecting to gdb failed

Tags: c++, netbeans, gdb, mingw

I have a problem in connecting to gdb after a fairly clean compilation.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/WFQ34.png

What is going on here?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

MinGW does not come with GDB (well it does but you need some more work). You are trying to debgu with dgb. Install gdb debugger.

Try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/170097/adding-gdb-to-mingw) question

Alternatively, I suggest you use visual studio for debugging

Good luck

Comment: Basically, I want to use Netbeans interactively/graphically debug blender. Do I absolutely need gdb anyways?

Comment: Netbeans needs a debugger to debug. Netbeans is just and IDE, which uses compiler (in your case, MinGW might have come with netbeans by default) and debugger to compile and to debug. So, yes, you need gdb(MinGW provides one) to debug

Comment: And again, MS visual studios is great IDE, I would personally used it if I used windows, but for learning purposes, I suggest you to install  a compiler (debugger should come with it) by hand and set up an IDE to use that

Comment: After overwriting the gdb tarball to the mingw64 directory, the same error occurs.

Comment: Check if the path to gdb.exe is correct (in netbeans options). Error 267 in netbeans indicates that it cannot find something(gdb in this case) (I googled the error)

Comment: Same error. I observe that there is a file called .gdbinit and don't know if that file matters, because it is not available in that path

Comment: Have you tried running gdb with cmd, does it even work (though it shouldnt be the case, since gdb exists)