# Eclipse -Error while launching command: gdb --version

Tags: c++, eclipse, debugging, gcc, gdb

I am using Eclipse on a Windows system (64-bit) for C++ code and the compiler is GCC/G++. I have created a .exe and in the end it is showing as amd64/le, and I am not able to debug. When I am trying to debug, I am getting the error as

> Error while launching command: gdb --version
>   CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified

1. Can you please let me know what is that amd64/le?
2. What is need to be done to debug?

Answer (score 8):

You can have a look at this [link](https://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/t/158165/). It helped me solve this problem just now,

The steps to follow are:

- Select Debug Configurations
- and click the Debugger tab
- now choose a GDB debugger by clicking *Browse* and selecting `gdb.exe` from the "bin" folder of your MinGW folder. If `gdb` is not present, navigate the command prompt to the bin folder and run `mingw-get.exe install gdb`.

*(Mostly it should be in something like `C:\Min_GW`).*

Comment: To install `gdb`, try https://stackoverflow.com/a/25628827/4573839

Answer (score 0):

AMD64/LE shows architecture / endianness. In your case architecture is [X86-64 alias AMD64](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86-64) and [endianness](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness) is [little](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness#Little-endian) (fixed on x86[64]).

As for your error message. It is possible that you did not install [GDB](https://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/) when you installed your toolchain. Verify that you have it installed.

It is also possible that you have bumped into [this bug](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=389823). Workaround is to check your path and remove any instances of ;; (like for example in c:\;;d:\, which is valid for most uses, but eclipse/cdt has issues with it).

Comment: Thanks , the issue was solved i have installed TDM-GCC-64, has a compiler and debugger inside.