# When calling a function in debug mode, GDB is crashed

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio-code, gdb, mingw

I'm trying to make a c++ program on Windows using MinGW.

The built program runs fine, Nevertheless, the problem occurs while debugging.

When debugging, If I try to inspect a execution result of function or method, like screenshots below, GDB is forced terminated.

I've ran GDB as a command line, the result has been the same though.

I also changed MinGW to different version, but to no avail.

GDB on WSL is working fine without any problems by the same configurations.

It's not working only on native Windows.

I would appreciate if you let me know why.

---

```
Just before watching "add(2, 3)".
```

[image]

```
ERROR: GDB exited unexpectedly. Debugging will now abort.
```

[image]

---

```
The same result of GDB command line.
"p v[1]", "p v.at(1)", "p v.empty()", "p v.size()", ... were failed,
"p add(2, 3)", "p my_obj.func()", ... were crashed.
```

[image]

---

```
G++ version is 8.1.0
gdb version is 8.1
```

[image]

Comment: trying to evaluate output of inlined methods of template may lead to that because function doesn't exist. GDB can evaluate only _existing_ function. If you would have a wrapped around such methods,  guaranteed not to be inlined, then it's possible to do, otherwise to debug container one should either know its implementation or rely on pretty-print.

Comment: @Swift-FridayPie Then why does the same code debugs fine on other platforms?
Should I consider it the problem with GDB ported to Windows?

Comment: Before certain version of G++ there were similar issues. GDB actually was patched around 7.0 version to have  that "pretty" print functionality to address that. rather  not-a-problem, but impelementation specific of compiler and runtime library. Note, mingw and mingw64 have not much in common with  GNU C++ compiler, they are independent projects. Difference simply is in modes of optimization. Try disable ALL optimizations and see if it works

Comment: @Swift-FridayPie I added `-O0` option. However, the result is the same.
It seems better not to use G++ on Windows. Thank you.

Comment: I just tried you example, and the same gdb commands, and it works fine on my windows.

Comment: do you have the directory containing gdb as the first entry in your `PATH` environment variable in the terminal from where you launch VSC. Maybe you have an exe name conflict on your path

Comment: Have you tried to update gdb to a latest version? Probably any version besides 8.1 will work, see https://sourceware.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=26304#c4.

Answer (score 2):

From personal experience this happens from time to time with MinGW. It can sometimes crash or throw all kinds of errors without an obvious cause.

Did a quick search and found some bug reports:

- https://forum.qt.io/topic/116248/latest-qt-creator-mingw-64-bit-build-gdb-crashes-when-hitting-breakpoints/2
- https://github.com/msys2/MINGW-packages/issues/3851

Looks like a potential bug in GDB 8.1. You can try using a different MinGW/GDB version, should fix the error.

Comment: `msys2` is lot more stable because of a different DLL/so placement/loading method

Answer (score 2):

It seems to be a bug with GDB [bug info](https://sourceware.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=26304) and seems to be reproduceable with:

> - set up 64-bit MinGW environment
> - compile and link a simple hello world c++ console application with gcc (also versioned 8.1.0)
> - start debugging EXE file with gdb
> - set breakpoint for instance on the main function (b main)
> - run info registers command (i r)
> - Debugger now unexpectedly quits and returns you to the command line.

If the website shows the correct information it seems like no one is currently working on it, but changing GDB version from `32-bit` to `64-bit` might resolve it.

Comment: "it seems like no one is currently working on it" - no, it was resolved as a duplicate of another already fixed bug.

Comment: @ks1322 I would not say the bug has been resolved if they only provided a workaround for it?

Comment: I don't see any workarounds in linked bug report. It was resolved because developers decided that the same problem was already reported in another bug.

Answer (score 2):

Most likely this is already resolved gdb bug https://sourceware.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=22854. It was reported for 8.1 version, see `Version: 8.1` in bug report. And it was fixed in 8.2 version, see `Target Milestone: 8.2` in bug report. You should update gdb to at least 8.2 version.

Comment: How can you do that within MinGW-w64? GDB 8.1 came bundled with the MinGW-w64 build.

Comment: Probably update whole MinGW-w64 or download a stand-alone binary, I don't know for sure, see https://stackoverflow.com/q/170097/72178.