# Code Blocks isn't showing any assembly code with debug mode

Tags: c, debugging, assembly, gdb, codeblocks

I'm having problems to see the assembly code generated from the source code. I know the debug mode in Code Blocks has a window named "disassembly" that should show the assembly code generated from the C source code, but every time I set a breakpoint, click the "run to cursor" option and enable the "disassembly" window, the debugging finishes with status 1 and doesn't show anything at all. Here is [a print of my debugger settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1X0QJ.png).

[image]

I'm new to debugging and would appreciate any useful information.
By the way, I'm on a Windows 10 ambient and it appears I'm using GNU GDB debugger at version 8.1 integrated with Code Blocks at version 20.03. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'd actually consider using CodeBlocks solely for debugging if that works. What happens when you run GDB from the command line like `gdb your_program`?

Comment: I'd tried and it works just fine... The problem only occurs in Code Blocks and I don't have any idea why... At my terminal it's possible to compile using gcc and debug using gdb, also it's possible to disassemble the code like I intend to do. At Code Blocks, however, it only let me see the "Watches" and "Memory dump" windows, but everytime I click on "Disassembly" or "CPU Registers", it terminates all of a sudden returning the status 1 from the debugger log...

Comment: gdb 8.1 had a [very nasty bug](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63809309/1983398) when debugging 64bit programs, so you should update.

Comment: Thank you very much, @ssbssa ! It really looks like a bug, I just had to update to version 12.1 using MSYS2 and now my Code Blocks debugging works just fine. Kinda sad the version I downloaded have this issue though...