# I am having trouble using GDB - "Cannot insert breakpoint" and "Cannot access memory" -- ASLR?

Tags: c++, windows, debugging, gdb

I ran into some problems developing a small program yesterday at the library and figured I would learn how to use the debugger installed with `Code::Blocks` that I assumed was working fine. I quickly realized that the debugger was returning 1 rather than running successfully, and after enabling full debugger logs I realized that warnings were being displayed that explained the debugger was having issues inserting a breakpoint and accessing a memory address.
I quickly wrote a simple "Hello World" program with a conditional statement to try and evaluate the statement at a breakpoint using the debugger, and received the same warnings.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    if(1)
    {
        cout << "Hello world!" << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

So, with the breakpoint at line 7, I receive warnings that the debugger is unable to insert Breakpoint 1, and the memory at address `0x140017dd` is unable to be accessed. After some short research I quickly discovered that this may be an issue involving `PIC/PIEs` (independently-executable code/executables) and `ASLR` (address layout randomization); and that I could disable the virtual address space randomization within `gdb` by way of the command line. Unfortunately, I quickly discovered that disabling randomization of the virtual address space through `gdb` is "unsupported on [my] platform" -- `Windows 11`. Now, I have disabled this through the exploit protection settings in `Windows Security` though I have found no resolve in the success of `gdb` within `Code::Blocks`.
I also know that this is not an issue regarding the version of `gdb`, as `version 8.1` returns the same error message regarding platform as `version 12.1`.

Is there a simple solution to this problem, or is there perhaps another debugger that I should use? I plan to delve into the details of compiling and debugging by way of the command line in the near-ish future (including the reading of assembler code and whatnot) but I do not yet wish to make the transition to `Linux`. If anyone has suggestions or a point in the right direction, I would greatly appreciate it.

EDIT: Adding a `MoveImages` value to the registry did not work either.
EDIT2: Here are the debugger logs:

```
Setting breakpoints

[debug]>>>>>>cb_gdb:
[debug]> show version
[debug]GNU gdb (GDB) 8.1
[debug]Copyright (C) 2018 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
[debug]License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>
[debug]This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
[debug]There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.  Type "show copying"
[debug]and "show warranty" for details.
[debug]This GDB was configured as "x86_64-w64-mingw32".
[debug]Type "show configuration" for configuration details.
[debug]For bug reporting instructions, please see:
[debug]<http://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/bugs/>.
[debug]Find the GDB manual and other documentation resources online at:
[debug]<http://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/documentation/>.
[debug]For help, type "help".
[debug]Type "apropos word" to search for commands related to "word".
[debug]>>>>>>cb_gdb:
[debug]> set confirm off

Debugger name and version: GNU gdb (GDB) 8.1

[debug]>>>>>>cb_gdb:
[debug]> set width 0
[debug]>>>>>>cb_gdb:
[debug]> set height 0
[debug]>>>>>>cb_gdb:
[debug]> set breakpoint pending on
[debug]>>>>>>cb_gdb:
[debug]> set print asm-demangle on
[debug]>>>>>>cb_gdb:
[debug]> set unwindonsignal on
[debug]>>>>>>cb_gdb:
[debug]> set print elements 200
[debug]>>>>>>cb_gdb:
[debug]> set new-console on
[debug]>>>>>>cb_gdb:
[debug]> set disassembly-flavor att
[debug]>>>>>>cb_gdb:
[debug]> directory ../CODEBL~1/DEBUGT~1/
[debug]Source directories searched: ../CODEBL~1/DEBUGT~1;$cdir;$cwd
[debug]>>>>>>cb_gdb:
[debug]> break "../CodeBlocks Projects/Debug Testing/main.cpp:7"
[debug]Breakpoint 1 at 0x1400017dd: file ..\CodeBlocks Projects\Debug Testing\main.cpp, line 7.
[debug]>>>>>>cb_gdb:
[debug]> run
[debug]Starting program: ..\CODEBL~1\DEBUGT~1\bin\Debug\DEBUGT~1.EXE 

Child process PID: 3916

[debug][New Thread 3916.0x27e8]
[debug][New Thread 3916.0x1f0]
[debug][New Thread 3916.0x1a40]
[debug]Warning:
[debug]Cannot insert breakpoint 1.
[debug]Cannot access memory at address 0x1400017dd
[debug]Command aborted.
[debug]>>>>>>cb_gdb:
[debug]> info frame

Debugger finished with status 1
```

EDIT: This was solved by pointing to a different installation of `MinGW` in `Code::Blocks`.

Comment: Step one, build your application with debug symbols (with `g++` this would be the `-ggdb` (or just `-g`) switch. Step two, to get a better debug experience, would be to build your code *without* optimization (`-O0`) (do that only for debugging, not for release).

Comment: I have the `-g` flag enabled, and I have no optimization flags enabled.

Comment: gdb handles ASLR correctly since version 10.1. Also, gdb 8.1 has a [very serious bug](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63809309/1983398), so you should update anyways.

Comment: Do you have any idea how to update *only* gdb? I don't think dragging and dropping the executable simply updates.

Comment: I'm pretty sure you can configure Code::Blocks to use a gdb from another path, wherever you have put the newer one.

Comment: @ssbssa All seems to be working now, pointing the debugger's directory to a separate installation of MinGW and its contained gdb. Thank you -- I will have some fun with this.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest that this is an issue of so basic optimization that it cannot be disabled. Take a look at this [Compiler Explorer example](https://godbolt.org/z/bnhYP8eW9). (flags: `-g -O0`, gcc 12.2 and Clang 15.0.0 behaves alike)

In my first function the `if(true)` completely disappears from the assembly.

```
void hello1()
{
    if(true)
    {
        cout << "Hello world!" << endl;
    }
}
```

While in the second example, the functionally equivalent `bool b = true; if(b)` results in actual instructions.

```
void hello2()
{
    bool b = true;
    if(b)
    {
        cout << "Hello world!" << endl;
    }
}
```

Interestingly, the `if` no longer appears if I make `b` `const`.

Try again with the code from `hello2`, because I think your problem is that you are asking gdb to break at a line that has no instructions.

Comment: I experience the same issue even with this code only at a different memory address. gdb cannot insert a breakpoint or access the memory address, for reasons seemingly unknown.