# Process returned -1073741819 (0xC0000005) execution time : 2.049 s

Tags: c++, error-handling

This one is really frustrating, I have no idea where it is coming from.

A little backstory

I am working on my chess game in c++, and currently I'm on the chess engine part. Everything is going on well, suddenly, at this very specific position of pieces on the board, this error comes

```
Process returned -1073741819 (0xC0000005)   execution time : 2.049 s
```

Press any key to continue.

It comes during the calculation on the moves, it just stops in the middle and shows this error. The project itself isn't small. I haven't been able to narrow this error down to any of the functions, it just happens. I have read a lot about it and I have seen it being related to pointers?, I am not using them in my program, What can I do to start solving this issue?

I don't really know where the error comes from so I have no idea what code I can provide here.

I am using The Code::Blocks IDE with mingw compiler

Comment: This error happens when an address is accessed which is not part of the memory the process got from the OS. There are a variety of reasons for this: Access to wild pointers,  out of bound access to arrays, and a lot more. There is no other way than debugging your application and carefully watch what was accessed when (and before) the error happens.

Comment: FYI: [Visual Studio debugger documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/?view=vs-2019)

Comment: When the app stops in the debugger you should be able to inspect the call stack to get an idea what's causing the access violation.

Comment: maybe start by reading about [mcve]. Even if you cannot create one now, it may give you some inspiration on how to tackle the problem: reduce the code until you can locate the error. Also it sounds like you do no unittesting. Lots of code means big trouble, small pieces of code means small bugs. Last but not least: use a debugger

Comment: omg, out bounds access to arrays?, that might be exactly what it is. The whole project works with an array, all the functions work with it

Comment: @500-InternalServerError How can I perform this?

Comment: _I am using The Code::Blocks IDE with mingw compiler_ FYI: [SO: Adding gdb to MinGW](https://stackoverflow.com/q/170097/7478597), [Debugging with Code::Blocks](http://wiki.codeblocks.org/index.php/Debugging_with_Code::Blocks)

Comment: Another option could be to add "diagnostic" output to your application - i.e. print variable values which you consider as suspicious. Though, debugging is an essential skill for S/W development and worth to be learned.

Comment: @Scheff you were right. out of bounds array is my number one target now

Comment: On Linux, the perfect tool to use in such a case is *Valgrind*. I don't know which is the equivalent one on Windows.

Comment: _you were right_ That was easy. Access violations are the daily plague of most C++ developers and I listed the usual reasons... ;-)

Comment: @Scheff I did find the exact bug, I went into the minimax algorithm and outputted the move it is on, i traced back to that move when it stopped, set the board to that position and ran it again, now instead of stopping in the middle it immediately exitted the game, this is when I saw the pawn was on the 6th rank, after moving to the 7th rank it is supposed to promote, but as I didn't add that a function that is supposed to get pawn moves was misbehaving

Comment: On Windows there is Visual Studio 2019 which has a much better debugger that mingw.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're on linux and have command line executable, you can follow below steps

1. Run your executable inside gdb ( gdb ./your_executable )
2. Start running your executable by **run** command
3. This will crash your program inside gdb env.
4. Now enter **where** command to know full back trace of crash
5. You can also apply break point to that function ( break "fun_name" ) after knowing the location of crash and monitor its stack contents by entering **bt full**