# Double hashing closed hashing hash table issue

Tags: c, data-structures, hashtable, double-hashing

I don't understand what's wrong. I went through the program multiple times using the rubber ducky technique. What's the issue please?

```
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>

enum state {legitimate, empty, deleted};

typedef struct 
{

    enum state info;
    char *key;
    char *value;

}cell;

typedef struct 
{

    cell *cells;
    unsigned int size;

}hash_table;

 
unsigned int
hash1(const char *key, unsigned int size)
{
    unsigned int hash = 0;
    
    for(unsigned int i = 0; key[i]; i++)
    {
        hash = (hash << 5) + key[i];
    }

    return (hash%size);

}

unsigned int
hash2(const char *key)
{
    unsigned int hash = 0;
    unsigned int prime = 3;
    
    for(unsigned int i = 0; key[i]; i++)
    {
        hash = prime - (key[i] % prime);
    }

    return (hash);

}


hash_table*
initialize(unsigned int size)
{
    hash_table *H = malloc(sizeof(*H));
    H->cells = malloc(sizeof(*H->cells)*size);

    for(unsigned int i = 0; i<size; i++)
    {
        H->cells[i].info = empty;
    }

    return H;

}

unsigned int
find(hash_table *H, const char *key)
{
    unsigned int index = hash1(key, H->size);
    unsigned int hash = hash2(key);
    unsigned max = index;

    while(H->cells[index].key!=key && H->cells[index].info!=empty)
    {
        index = (index+hash)%H->size;

        if(index==max){printf("Not found!"); return -1;}
        if(index>=H->size){index-=H->size;}

    }

    return index;
    

}

void
insert(hash_table *H, const char *key, const char *value)
{
    unsigned int index = find(H, key);

    if(H->cells[index].info!=legitimate)
    {

        H->cells[index].key= malloc(strlen(key)+1);
        H->cells[index].value = malloc(strlen(value)+1);


        strcpy(H->cells[index].key,key);
        strcpy(H->cells[index].value,value);

        H->cells[index].info = legitimate;

    }
}

void
dump(hash_table *H)
{
    for(unsigned int i = 0; i<H->size; i++)
    {   
        if(H->cells[i].info!=legitimate){continue;}

        printf("Index[%d]: %s\n", i, H->cells[i].value);
    }
}


int main()
{
    hash_table *H = initialize(10);
    insert(H,"name1","David");
    insert(H, "name2", "Radka");
    dump(H);
    return 0;
}
```

OUTPUT:

```
NO OUTPUT
```

I checked if hash1(), hash2(), and find() functions work, and they do, checked with multiple inputs everything seemed to work as it should.
I am not sure what is missing or what I did wrong. Please help.

Comment: It's hard to answer your question because it doesn't include a [mre]. Please [edit] your question to include your code, sample input and output, and any error messages. Tell us what you expect to happen as well as what's actually happening. This will help us answer your question better.

Comment: It seems you forgot to initialize `H->size` in the `initialize()` function.

Comment: @JohnKugelman Thank you, done.

Comment: @MikeCAT Thank you so much!!!!

Comment: You mean you intentionally left `H->size` uninitialized if you didn't forget that? Initialize it to proper value (not zero because it is used in division) anyway.

Comment: In `find`: `while (H->cells[index].key!=key && H->cells[index].info!=empty)`. The comparison for `key` just compares the _address_ of the strings for inequality and _not_ the strings themselves. Although sometimes [rarely] okay, the usual way to compare strings is to use `strcmp`. So, I think you need: `while (strcmp(H->cells[index].key,key) != 0 && H->cells[index].info!=empty)` But, then you'd be dereferencing a pointer that may not be valid. Reverse the order: `while (H->cells[index].info!=empty && strcmp(H->cells[index].key,key) != 0)` to take advantage of "short circuit" evaluation

Comment: @CraigEstey Damn, that's very well explained. Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

Since your program generates a core dump, you can take advantage of that

Run your program, you get

> Floating point exception (core dumped)

When a process terminates unexpectedly it generates a file with the process memory contents (a snapshot of the program at the time of the crash). Since core file creation is disabled by default, we use the `ulimit` command to enable writing core files:

Open a console and set the process resources limit to `unlimited`

```
ulimit -c unlimited
```

Run again your program to generate the core file

Launch the debugger using the generated core file

```
> gdb demo core

Program terminated with signal SIGFPE, Arithmetic exception.
#0  0x000055cd5fe03202 in hash1 (key=0x55cd5fe04024 "name1", size=0) at demo.c:35
35      return (hash%size);
```

It crashes at `hash1()`, lets see why:

```
(gdb) print hash
$1 = 118636753
(gdb) print size
$2 = 0
```

You got it! dividing by zero in `return (hash%size);`

The prototype of `hash1` is

```
unsigned int hash1(const char *key, unsigned int size);
```

Check who is calling `hash1()` with `size` set to 0:

```
(gdb) frame 1
#1  0x0000555555555309 in find (H=0x5555555592a0, key=0x555555556024 "name1") at demo.c:73
73      unsigned int index = hash1(key, H->size);
```

`H->size` is the culprit, it is used uninitialized.

```
hash_table*
initialize(unsigned int size)
{
    hash_table *H = malloc(sizeof(*H));
    H->cells = malloc(sizeof(*H->cells)*size);

    for(unsigned int i = 0; i<size; i++)
    {
        H->cells[i].info = empty;
    }
    H->size = size; // Initialize it here
    return H;
}
```

Comment: thank you so much! Although I did not understand your first 2 steps. 
_Ok, open a console and set the process resources limit to unlimited_ 
and
_Launch the debugger using your generated core_

How, where and why do I set it to unlimited. And what exactly is demo core?

Comment: I have edited the answer explaining those steps, I don't know if you are using Linux or some unix, in such case you can reproduce all the steps, on Windows you can use [MinGW](http://www.mingw.org/) with [gdb support](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/170097/adding-gdb-to-mingw)

Comment: thank you! I spend the whole night installing MinGW and reviewing the basics of gdp, now it makes more sense.

Comment: I'd like to ask, what does frame do and how does it work please?